# C# - How to have a dictionary of different class properties

Tags: c#

Let's say I have this class

```
    public class Fruit
    {
        //all the fruit types
        public string apple;
        public string orange;
        public string grape;
    }
```

I want a dictionary where I can add Fruit properties. `Dictionary<Fruit, string> fruitDict` where I can do fruitDict.add(Fruit.apple, "1") or `fruitDict.add(orange, "2")`. What would be the best way of designing this? Would the best way making my properties enum?

Comment: Make your "fruits" an enum.

Comment: seems like you look for an enum instead of a string for the keys in your dictionary. Then you can write fruitDict.Add(Fruit.Apple, "1")

Comment: might also use an int instead of a string "1"...

Comment: This is a weird question. Apple is not a property of Fruit; it is a *type* of Fruit. This suggests inheritance instead of composition. Are you sure you got the assignment right?

Comment: That class has no properties - those are fields

Comment: @Plutonix way to miss the point. I'm talking entities, not code.

Comment: thanks everyone...I guess enum would do it!

Comment: @JohnWu what makes you think that was directed to you?  In addition to enums, it was a nit regarding the gap in the OP's fields/properties/attributes understanding.

Comment: @plutonix Adjacency. But I understand now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I know about fruit, I'm guessing you are actually looking for a list that can hold three kinds of fruit, like this:

```
abstract class Fruit
{
}
class Apple : Fruit
{
}
class Orange : Fruit
{
}
class Grape : Fruit
{
}

var fruitList = new List<Fruit>
{
    new Apple(),
    new Orange(),
    new Grape()
};
```

If on the other hand you really want a class that can contain various fruits, maybe this is what you want:

```
enum FruitType { Apple, Grape, Orange }

class FruitBasket : Dictionary<FruitType,int>
{
    public void AddFruit(FruitType fruitType, int count)
    {
        if (!this.ContainsKey(fruitType))
        {
            this.Add(fruitType, 0);
        }
        this[fruitType] += count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, I was basically looking for enums